# Import issue when using Azure Function runtime and pytest 'ModuleNotFoundError'

Tags: python, azure-functions, pytest, importerror

I have a project structure that looks like this:

```
repo/
   |--model/api
      |--function/function_app.py
      |--function/tool.py
      |--function/__init__.py
      |--tests/test_function_app.py
      |--tests/__init__.py
```

Running function_app.py using `func start` in repo/ requires me to import tool.py using `from tool import someFunction`.

When I run pytest however, I get: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tool'`

If I switch the import to `from function.tool import someFunction`, pytest works but running the function using `func start` returns a  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'function'`.

Putting the test files in the same directory as the function without `__init__.py` makes both the function and test work.

I could do this and just delete the test files when deploying the function, but what's the better way to do this?

**I was able to get this to work by referencing the relevant [MSDOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators)**

My repository structure now looks like:

```
repo/
   |--model/api
      |--function/function_app.py
           |--tools/tool.py
           |--tools/__init__.py
           |--tests/test_function_app.py
           |--tests/__init__.py
```

Where I can now import `from function_app import function_function` in my tests and `from tools import tool` in my function_app. I now reference the function using `tool.function` in function_app.

Comment: What version are you using V1 or V2, i see you are using functionapp.py and init.py , both are from diff versions

Comment: you need to add this -**sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))**

Comment: @admeer you are running `func start` in directory `repo/` or `repo/model/api/function`
In which folder your `host.json` file and `reqirements.txt` files are available

Comment: @admeer when you run `pytest` without mentioning any file it runs all the test files insde the whole directory. so when you are running `from function.tool import someFunction` pytest is working because  py test is running files inside the test folder as per that `function.tool` is correct syntax.

Comment: When all my function files are inside `function` folder `from tool import get_value` works fine when i execute the function. [execution](https://i.imgur.com/QNy8Xsy.png)  [output](https://i.imgur.com/4Fq4pCe.png)

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya That's my bad. I am running `func start` from `repo/model/api/function`. You are correct - `from tool import get_value` works fine for the function, but when I run `pytest` my tests break and say they can't find module tool. Did you get `from function import tool` to work when executing the function? When I run the function and I have an import that references the module that the function sits in - it doesn't work.

Comment: I _was_ able to get both the function and tests to work by referencing the relevant [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators).

Comment: @admeer that's my bad. `from function import tool` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

when `pytest` executed without mentioning any file it runs all the test files inside the directory. so when you are running `from function.tool import someFunction`, `pytest` is working because `pytest` is running files inside the test folder as per that `function.tool` is correct syntax. as I mentioned in comment.

**#My Directory**

```
Python/
│
├── model/
│ ├── api/
│ | ├── Function/
| | | ├── __init__.py
| | | ├── function_app.py
| | | ├── tool.py
| | | ├── tool.py
| | | ├── host.json
| | | ├── requirements.txt
| | | └── ...
| | |
| | ├── test/
| | | ├── __init__.py
| | | └── test_app.py
| | | 
| └── ...
|
└── ...
```

[image]

when running `func start` to run `function_app.py`  use `from tool import get_value` to work, `pytest` won't work for absolute import.

**`function_app.py`:**

```py
import azure.functions as func
from tool import get_value
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    return func.HttpResponse(
             f"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. \n \n{get_value()}",
             status_code=200
        )
```

**`tool.py`:**

```py
def get_value():
    result= "this message is from tool.py"
    return result
```

> **Note:** `from  function.tool  import  get_value` will work in `pytest`

**`test_app.py`:**

```py
from function.tool import get_value
def test_value():
    return f"this is test from test_app\n {get_value()}"
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

[image]

[image]

[image]